# Chovos Halevavos vs. Mesilas Yesharim

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study, jewish-books, mussar-ethics

The three basic texts that R' Yisroel Salanter wanted people to learn were [Chovos HaLevavos](http://dafyomireview.com/article.php?docid=384), [Mesilas Yesharim](http://www.shechem.org/torah/mesyesh/) and Cheshbon HaNefesh.
(source: [here](http://rabbisedley.blogspot.co.il/2008/12/ben-franklin-and-cheshbon-hanefesh.html))

what is the difference between Chovos Halevavos and Mesilas Yesharim

which book should a beginner focus on first and why?

what about someone more advanced?

Comment: This question would be a great deal more compelling if you'd include some information about why you think that anyone should learn either of these works, why a beginner should, and why a beginner and a more advanced student may have different needs here.

Comment: ...and what you're considering a "beginner".

Comment: There is no order...read both!! At least, read both introductions. You will understand what is the idea of each one...

Comment: Like the introduction of messilat yesharim said, you always have to read the messilat yesharim....again and again

Comment: "Chovos Halevavos vs. Mesilas Yesharim" sounds like a frum action movie satire.

Comment: `what is the difference between Chovos Halevavos and Mesilas Yesharim` Seems too broad; the answer could probably fill a book. `which book should a beginner focus on first and why?` Seems primarily opinion based. `what about someone more advanced?` You get the idea...

Comment: Today in Yeshivot, mesilat yesharim is the more used. the remark or @user9655 is not true, someone who learn musar does not become depressed and someone who learn chasidut does not become manic. The mesilat yesharim is easy to read more and more, is more congruent with the Torah world today. Chovot Halevavot has difficulties: an old cultural background which is generally not known by yeshivot people. It is a translation, in a scholastic medieval hebrew, very different e.g. from the language of Mishne Torah and last loshon Hakodesh books.

Comment: @kouty I hear what you mean but certain sections of CH are very popular. the shaar bitachon for example is recommended broadly by a wide diversity of rabbis

Answer (score 11):

[Rabbi Shlomo Aviner](http://www.maale.org.il/joomla/noar/pluginclass?plugin=cbgroupjive&action=plugin&func=group_shoot&cat=2&grp=2&id=133547) suggests that Mesilas Yesharim (MY) be studied before Chovos Halevavos (CH) since MY is a written in a more accessible style and the topics are more basic. CH is deeper and the language is harder.

THinking about it some more with MY you will come away with more actionable tasks. i.e zerisus, zehiros, etc.. with CH the take aways are more in the realm of thought and contemplation (i.e Bitachon, Belief in Gods' unity, etc... )The author of CH calls those things which are actionable "Duties of the limbs" whereas he writes that his sefer (CH) focuses on those traits that are dependent on contemplation - "Duties of the heart" hence the name of the sefer.

I feel that they are both great and you should get yourself a teacher and start right away. you wont lose with either and understanding one book is not dependent on understand the other.

Comment: Some secular people seem to grab on to the ordered lifestyle that the Torah offers so in that case MY is a good choice. Most Mussar teachers did not learn SHaar HaYichud and Shaar HaBechina. If Kiruv is the goal you may want to consider Derech HaShem as well

Comment: See [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5459/69) for a discussion of whether one should study the philosophical proofs of God's existance in Chovot HaLevavot's Sha'ar HaYichud or not.

Comment: but you can read lev tov translation which is modern hebrew much easier than original language of Mesilat Yeshorim

Comment: I realize this is an old answer, but your link is dead. It's a great answer, regardless.

Comment: Nefesh HaMesila commentary to MY: it is possible for a person to read this book many times and miss the point entirely. We would like to emphasize the matter for it is such an important foundation of the book.
When the Ramchal reveals how a person can change his nature and acquires the various successive levels, he reveals that the main path to use is "reflection and consideration". In the words of the Ramchal "hitbonenut" and "histaklut". he says "think on this and this point and acquire the trait of Watchfulness". (continued)

Comment: "think on this and this point and acquire the trait of cleanliness." so too for each level. The primary path which the Ramchal explains is not on doing many acts and deeds or even words but rather the main path is thinking and contemplating. Only a few rare times he speaks the need for deeds to acquire a certain level but he writes it in such a way as to make clear that the main change is attained through thought and then the deeds are drawn to follow along

Comment: ...Behold you can see that when the Ramchal explains that the external [zeal] awakens the internal [fieriness] he does not mention this in the chapter of Acquiring Zeal (ch.8) but rather in the chapter of the Divisions of Zeal (ch.7). But in the chapter of Acquiring Zeal he makes no mention whatsoever of the deeds! It is entirely devoted to the thoughts to think of in order to acquire Zeal.

Answer (score 3):

Mesilat Yesharim is short and straight to the point while Chovos Halevavos is much longer and gives alot of background such as trusting in God.

The trait of Zehirus (watchfulness) starts immediately after the introduction in Mesilat Yesharim.

In Chovos Halevavos, the trait of zehirus (watchfulness) starts in Gate #3 after many introductions.

So bottom line I think is that it depends on the needs of the person.

The Mesilas Yesharim is a kind of concise road map to set a person straight on the correct path of ascending the spiritual ladder. It is good for people who already want to grow but they are confused as to the correct path to follow (or they know but want to be reminded).

The Chovos Halevavos on the other hand is also a comprehensive work on Jewish philosophy and laying down foundations to inspire the reader to want to grow.

Update: found this in the [commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41769&st=&pgnum=69&hilite=) of Rabbi Yechezkel Sarna to Mesilat Yesharim (ch.8):

> From here we can also learn on the concise style of the Ramchal. For
>   the Shaar Bechina is a large gate (section) in the giant work of
>   Rabeinu Bachye who was one of the Rishonim (early) sages who are well
>   known for their concise language. The Ramchal summarized it all in
>   just a few lines thus fulfilling his obligation to mention the duty of
>   Examination which is so essential in the service of G-d. And perhaps
>   also this itself is the cause it for since the matters can be found in
>   the Chovos Halevavos, for this reason, the Ramchal did not expound it
>   further. Likewise the Ramchal did not go at length on the subject of
>   the Gate of Spiritual Accounting (of the Chovos Halevavos) and even on
>   the Gate of Trust (Shaar Bitachon) he mentioned only hintingly while
>   Rabeinu Bachye expounded such huge gates. But the Ramchal sufficed
>   only in fixing the need for the [spiritual] accounting (in
>   Watchfulness) and he left the details of the ways of the accounting
>   [for Gate 8 of Chovos Halevavos]. **From here were see that this book is
>   a book of klalim (general principles) not one of details (pratim)**.